# Can I use a non-Apple made lightning to USB cable to reinstall iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, usb

I want to roll back to iOS 14 because iOS 15 literally ruined my life.

I have an iPad (8th generation). This is my first Apple device and the cable that came with it is a lightning to lightning cable.

I have a Windows PC so I was looking for a USB to lightning connector on Apple’s website. It’s kinda expensive.

Can I use a non-Apple made USB to lightning connector for the same goal? Most importantly, would my device be recognised by iTunes?

Comment: Never, ever, seen a lightning to lightning cable. Apple ships a USB (A or C) to Lightning with all iPhones and iPads. I don't know what you mean about a "duplicate usb to lightning connector." But you can buy USB to Lightning cable anywhere and as long as it is not listed as a "charging" cable (which only has the leads for power connected) it should work fine.

Comment: Ye it’s a usb A to lightning lol. By duplicate I mean, a usb to lightning cable which isn’t from apple

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think your questions about the cabling situation doesn't really matter now. The major problem here is that you cannot downgrade to iOS 14 without having the software signed by Apple for your device - and Apple has stopped doing that for iOS 14 for that iPad.

So I'm afraid you cannot downgrade to iOS 14 - no matter which cable you use.

Comment: You can, however, probably find a used iPad with IOS 14 if you look around enough.

Answer (score -1):

Lightning connectors have visible metal contacts and USB C connectors have them hidden inside a metal sleeve.

Sounds like you received a USB C to USB C cable in the box and what you are looking for is a traditional USB A to USB C.

Any brand cable should work fine and show up in iTunes. If in doubt, avoid the cheapest cable.

Comment: New iPad will come with USB-C to Lightning. OP needs USB A to Lightning. You can get these for next to nothing these days from eBay or any supermarket.